# ReactJS Bootstrap Navbar not in one line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, header, navbar, react-bootstrap

I want to add Navigation Bar to my website using Bootstrap in ReactJS. But all NavItems are on separate lines. How to put them on one line. I followed the guide in Bootstrap docs.

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCvQc.png)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Header extends Component {
render() {
return(
  <div className="Header">
    <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
      <Navbar.Header>
      </Navbar.Header>
      <Navbar.Collapse>
        <Nav pullLeft>
          <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">
            Link1
          </NavItem>
          <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">
            Link2
          </NavItem>
        </Nav>
        <Nav pullRight>
          <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">
            Link3
          </NavItem>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
  </div>
)
}
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: Have you added the stylesheet?

Comment: Nope, I did not

Comment: React Bootstrap only provides the Javascript. You still need to add the CSS

Comment: I am really new to React. Could you provide more info on this?

Comment: See the answer by Daniel

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings how to customize navbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add de css to your index.html, from your package or from the CDN.

check this [Link for more info](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: Thanks, Dan! Works

Comment: by default,  you can change the style of your Navbar with the `bsStyle` prop. see https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/

BTW: you can override css adding classnames, but I don't recommend to override or edit  bootstrap classes

Answer (score 0):

[Working Demo is here]    [codesendbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/l5nn7r11wz)